# send variable throught link to controller laravel [UPDATE - fixed]

Tags: php, html, laravel, routes, controller

can someone help me with sending variable trough link like letter ? (when user click on letter), and controller return movies which begin with the selected initial letter.

There is my index.blade.php :

```
        <?php
        $letters= range('A', 'Z'); 
        ?>
        
        <h4>Movies with letter -?- </h4>
        @foreach($letters as $letter)

        <a href='{{$letter}}'>{{$letter}}</a>
                
        @endforeach
```

and  there is my route :

```
Route::put('/{letter}','App\Http\Controllers\MoviesController@show');
```

There is controller function :

```
       public function show( $letter)
       {
        $letter= $letter;
       
        $colection= DB::table('movies')
            ->where('title', 'like', $letter.'%')
            ->get()  ;  
            
        return view( 'index', ['colection' => $colection] );            }
```

thanks all for the help!

Comment: Change this line `public function show($letter)` and remove `$letter= $request->letter;` and your route method is put, so you cant use a get method with this `<a href="" > {{$letter}} </a>`

Comment: If you want to pass data with anchor link, then change your route `put` to `get` and this line should be like `<a href="/catch/{{ $letter }}" > {{$letter}} </a>`

Comment: Clear route cache `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: you need javascript to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $letters= range('A', 'Z'); 
    ?>
    
    @foreach($letters as $letter)

    <a href="catch/{{$letter}}" > {{$letter}} </a>                    
          
    @endforeach
```